# "Mistaken as" vs. "mistaken for"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, prepositions

I heard someone use the words *mistaken as* rather than *mistaken for*.

Is this correct? If it is correct then what is the difference between the two? Is it ever wrong to use *mistaken as*, and if so, why?

I ask because I was recently advised about something:

> It shouldn't in any way be mistaken as an academic judgement.

In dictionary definitions and usage guides, the preposition used is given as *for*, not *as*. However, there are other examples with *as*, such as ones in comments below, as well as in books on the internet.

Comment: Hello RAFATH. If you show the people here the attempts you yourself have made to address your questions, eg examples given in dictionaries and occurring on the internet, it would be closer to the type of question the Help Center expects.

Comment: "I was mistaken as a doctor" or "I was mistaken for a doctor" what is the meaning and difference between the two?

Comment: How many 'hits' do you get for each of these on Google? Do you think that one of your versions might possibly be ungrammatical, only used by people whose grammar is suspect?

Comment: @RAFATH: I'm sure most dictionaries (incl. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistake)) will give example usages for ***mistaken for***, but none will feature ***mistaken as***. Which as you'll see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+mistaken+as+a%2Cwas+mistaken+for+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20mistaken%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20mistaken%20for%20a%3B%2Cc0) virtually never occurs. It's not "ungrammatical" - it's just not *idiomatic*. Sorry, but the question is General Reference.

Comment: “It should in no way be mistaken as an academic judgment”
“It shouldn’t in any way be mistaken for an academic judgment”.I came across it today.

Comment: I often came across a pupil – sometimes a very intelligent one – who got a maths question wrong. I'd disagree with FF, and say that 'mistaken as X', like 'mistaken behind X', is ungrammatical. It's a wrong construction, coupling a verb phrase and preposition in a non-accepted usage. Collins: mistake vb, -takes, -taking, -took or -taken

4. **(foll by: for)** to take (for), interpret (as), or confuse (with): she mistook his direct manner for honesty. [bolding mine]

Comment: @FumbleFingers Edwin, I'm not sure. My intuition is that OP's example in comments is acceptable. *was mistaken as an indication of*,  *was mistaken as evidence of* and the like seem ok. I think data, communicative functions, intents - stuff that needs interpreting - can be *(mis)taken as*. General entities - including data etc can be *mistaken for*. The former would be far more restricted. Entities that are recognised, not interpreted, will give us very strong ungrammaticality judgements: *Don't mistake me as Bob*. Compare with *Don't mistake this drop as evidence of a decline ...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Edwin The answers here are categorically wrong. If you mistake Bob for Mark, you do not recognise that Bob is Bob, you think he is Mark. If you mistake a fall in revenue as an indication of an economic downturn, you correctly identify the fall in revenue. It fully exists. It is the wrong *interpretation* of the accurately  recognised fall as an indication of something else that is awry. In the troublesome comment made to the OP, whatever it is that shouldn't be interpreted as an academic judgement, is probably identified accurately. For example, a score in an essay.

Comment: @Araucaria: I think you're conflating *mistake* and *take*, which obviously not all native speakers are able/willing to do (Edwin goes so far as to say *mistake as* is "ungrammatical). My link to M-W in my original closevote comment includes the example *I mistook him **for** his brother*, and Edwin cites Collins as saying *(foll by: **for**)*. Clearly the standard preposition *can* be found using easily available references. I see no point in re-opening just so we can argue about exactly *how* "wrong" the non-standard ***as*** is.

Comment: Well the reason is that the OP was told (presumably by his supervisor) "It should in no way be mistaken as an academic judgement". There is also the fact that the truth value effects of the two are potentially different. The standard reading  with *for*: X was not recognised as X, but was perceived as Y and NOT X. With *as* the reading is restricted to: X was recognised as X, but wrongly thought to also be Y. This reading is allowed by "for" but the other is ruled out by "as". It may therefore avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Araucaria: I understand the distinction you're trying to make, and it may be you're not the only one who would make it. But I think as a percentage of all Anglophones you'd be in such a tiny minority it's not a usable principle (hardly anyone would understand your intent if you relied on just that non-standard preposition use to convey it). Anyway, as well as a dictionary link, my closewvote comment included a link to an NGram showing how relatively uncommon *mistaken as* is. I see no support for your distinction in such instances as *do* occur in that link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about this one? It still shows 'mistaken for' to be more prevalent, but 'mistaken as' puts in some kind of showing ... (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mistaken+as+evidence%2C+mistaken+for+evidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmistaken%20as%20evidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmistaken%20for%20evidence%3B%2Cc0)[for v as]

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also worth a gander: (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mistaken+as+evidence%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22mistaken+as+evidence%22&tbm=bks)[M as evidence] You may have to turn on the Books filter. Can't get it to stay set ...

Comment: @Araucaria: I read both those *"**as** evidence"* searches as evidence that "as evidence" is a relatively common collocation in other contexts. I'd also point out that non-native speakers are particularly likely to be involved in *scientific* writings (where *evidence* tends to occur more often). Like you, many such people are simply conflating *mistake* with *take*. I don't deny you have a point in that the usage is becoming more common, but OP wasn't specifically asking about *"mistaken as **evidence**"*. Let's leave it there - I'm not going to vote to reopen, and that's that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd already posted a comment that it may not be worth reopening. Don't what's happened to it, appears to have been ghosted away. Last two links and the one that was in that comment itself were just for interest. I'm not really a fan of Ngrams at all ...

Comment: @Araucaria *"It shouldn't in any way be mistaken **as** an academic judgement."* It sounds okay to me. :)

Comment: Doesn't "I was mistaken as a doctor" or "I was mistaken for a doctor" say it all?

"I was mistaken as a doctor" is a very obscure case, but everyone I know would recognise it as meaning "I am a doctor and what I said was wrong."

"I was mistaken for a doctor" is a common linguistic structure meaning, for instance "because we were in a hospital and I was dressed (this, that or whatever way), someone wrongly thought I was a doctor."

Answer (score 1):

Usually, "mistaken for" is used when the speaker is refering to something with an identity (anything with mass)- that is a person, or an object.

Ex: He was *mistaken for* her husband as he was sitting by her side.

"Mistaken as" is used when the speaker is refering to some kind of an action, say, judgement in this question.

Ex: Since he spoke like an angel, his intentions were *mistaken as* good [or honorable]

Comment: I think that this is a good summary of the distinction between _mistaken for_ and _mistaken as_, except that I would change your final example to this: _Since he spoke like an angel, his intentions were mistaken as good [or honorable]._

Comment: Thanks @SvenYargs, you are right. The sentence provides more clarity with your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

When people mix up intangible things, and "as" is used after "mistook" to explain it, people are sometimes confused as to which way to word the sentence. Let's say a headstone engraver was working from a sloppy handwritten order and thought the date of birth was 1949 when it was actually 1948. Did he mistake 1948 as 1949 or 1949 as 1948? Just remember that the correct information comes first in the sentence and the incorrect information follows the word "as": he mistook 1948 as 1949, not the other way around. A helpful way to remember this is to (mentally) change the word "mistook" to a more specific word. "He misread 1948 as 1949" leaves no doubt about which date is the correct one. Whatever a person mistook is the same as what he misread or misheard.